# Перевести английские символы на русские

Tags: c++

Нужно перевести английские символы на русские отталкиваясь от их положения на клавиатуре, например ghbdtn -> привет, если просто сдвигать по таблице ASCII получится жзбгун, может быть существует решение без захардкодживания этого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никакими сдвигами не добьетесь, т.к. никакая кодировка не задает взаимного расположения кнопок на клавиатуре в различных языках. Захардкоживание - наиболее практичный вариант.

P.S. Обратите внимание на то, что бывают еще и различные раскладки, такие как QWERTY / AZERTY или Дворака, они, естественно, тоже никак не записываются в текстовом файле содержащем "ghbdtn".

Answer (score 0):

авось кому пригодится

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     SetConsoleCP(1251);
     SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
     string alphabE = "f,dult;pbqrkvyjghcnea[wxi.z";
     string alphabR = "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшюя";

     map<char,char> alphabet;

     for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        char buff = alphabE[i];
        alphabet[buff]=alphabR[i];
     }
     cout << "Input string" << endl;
     string myInp;
     cin >> myInp;
     for(int i = 0; i < myInp.size(); i++){
        char buffer = myInp[i];
        myInp[i] = alphabet[smt];
     }
     cout << endl << myInp << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: не думаю, что кому то понадобится